# Why do I get precision issue when using SqlServer float in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting too manydecimals when I insert a float in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblick](
    [DATA] [float] NULL
)
```

Here is SqlCommand setup:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO FOD..tblick VALUES(@DATA)";
cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DATA", SqlDbType.Float);
```

Here I use command:

```
string fieldA = "1.09726";
float Bid = float.Parse(fieldA);
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is what I get in sql server table:

```
DATA
1.09725999832153
```

Why?

Comment: float is imprecise. If you want decimal precision use `decimal`

Comment: You are probably compiling in debug mode instead of release.  VS in debug mode calculates floating point using a software emulation while in release mode you are using the microcomputer floating point arithmetic unit (FPU).  The SQL Server is using the FPU.  You will get a different value in some cases between debug and release.

Comment: @MartinSmith - For the right range of values `decimal` is more precise than `float`, but it is still only a digital representation of a real number - so, it too, is imprecise.